# Eager loading nested association and scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner and it's hard to explain my problem:

My models:

```
class Skill  
  has_many :categories
  has_many :positions, :through => :categories
end

class Category
  belongs_to :skill
  has_many :positions  
end

class Position
  belongs_to :category
  has_one :skill, :through => :category    
end
```

I can successfully eager load everything, like this:

```
@skills = Skill.includes(:positions)
```

However sometimes I want to apply a scope on the Positions:

```
class Position
...
  scope :active, where(:hidden => false)
end
```

**I wish I could do:**

```
@skills = Skill.includes(:positions.active)
```

Instead, I apply the scope in the views, but the eager loading doesn't work anymore:

```
<%= skill.positions.acitve ... %>
```

Is it possible to have both eager loading and scope?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use another association:

```
class Skill  
  has_many :categories
  has_many :positions, :through => :categories
  has_many :active_positions, :through => :categories
end

class Category
  belongs_to :skill
  has_many :positions  
  has_many :active_positions, :class_name => "Position", :conditions => {:hidden => false}
end

class Position
  belongs_to :category
  has_one :skill, :through => :category    
end
```

And then

```
@skills = Skill.includes(:active_positions)
```

But then you'll get two associations. If you ever use `skill.positions`, all the skill's positions will be loaded from the database. You should only use `skill.active_positions`.

Comment: Thank you Michaël. It worked perfectly. I used some if/else in the controller (if the user is logged_in), and also if/else in the views, like: <% user_signed_in? ? skill.positions : skill.active_positions %>

Comment: For  rails 6+ you can do it like this                                                                    has_many :incomp_bookings, -> { where(bookings: { status: :incomplete }) }, class_name: 'Booking'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@skills = Skill.includes(:positions).where('position.active = TRUE')
```

Comment: It returns: "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: position.active ..."

Comment: It's maybe because the table is called 'positions', so it should be 'positions.active' (you're referring to the table here, not the Model.

Comment: You can't use a `where` condition here because when Rails eager loads, it makes two requests. You could use such a condition with a `join` but it has nothing to do with eager loading.

Comment: The 'where' jeopardises the eager loading effort.