# Eager loading of deleted records with paranoia's default scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, eager-loading, default-scope

I'm using the [paranoia](https://github.com/radar/paranoia) gem to "soft-delete" records. Now I need to eager load these records, some of which might have been deleted, for an associated model. Paranoia adds this `default_scope` to the "paranoid" model:

```
default_scope :conditions => { :deleted_at => nil }
```

So in effect, I have these (simplified) models:

```
class Product
  has_many :orders
  default_scope :conditions => { :deleted_at => nil }
end

class Order
  belongs_to :product
end
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to eager-load the products when accessing orders:

```
Order.includes(:product)
```

This (from [How to use unscoped on associated relations in Rails3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758145/how-to-use-unscoped-on-associated-relations-in-rails3)) does not work here:

```
Product.unscoped { Order.includes(:product) }
```

I know I could create a custom `belongs_to` relationship to *add* conditions (as in [Eager loading nested association and scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169828/eager-loading-nested-association-and-scope)), but I can't find a way to *remove* existing ones, if that's even possible.

**Question:** How do I prevent the default scope from being applied to the eager loading query?

Comment: Just found this related question, which is still unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963124/default-scope-and-associations?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it turns out the workaround is to force a join on the "paranoid" model, which circumvents the `default_scope`:

```
Order.joins(:product).includes(:product)
```

Not pretty, but it works. Would like a better answer if possible.

Answer (score 2):

This bug is fixed in rails >= 4.1.8.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11036

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17360